# How to find when OS is last updated in java

Tags: java

I want to know when OS is last updated(for Linux and Widnows) programmatically in java. Is there any way to find it? Any ideas!!

Comment: Once we describe in a non-platform specific manner what "updated" means, this should be no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot i found the way to do this programmatically. Here's how it can be achieved:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic qfe list");
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

If you want brief details then you can use command `wmic qfe list brief`.
You'll see a complete list of windows update history **including that update installed on which date**.
The command which is to be used for this purpose will vary platform to platform. **For linux you can use command** `yum history`.
This is the [Reference link](http://kb.hyve.com/wiki/List%20installed%20security%20patches%20and%20updates%20in%20windows) which helped me on.

Comment: This will only work on Windows, though. It does not answer your "for any platform" requirement

Comment: Yeah you right, command will vary platform to platform.

Comment: This is one of the SMS tools I mentioned in one of my last comments. This question sort of belongs over on one of the server admin SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is nothing in the Oracle APIs that knows anything about the upgrade state of the system a VM might be running on.

You could determine a set of heuristics that you can use to determine the upgrade state of a given host system, and then write the platform specific parts of that, switching on `System.getProperties("os.version")` and friends.

The hard part is determining those heuristics. They'll be different for different systems, versions, releases...

It does occur to me that these are the sorts of things that get covered in the Apache Commons classes. If anyone has even minimal support for this sort of thing, they will.

Followup prompted by comments:

Apache Commons doesn't seem to have this, which is not surprising.

At the end of the day, my first offhand comment is still the key question: what does "upgrade" mean for those systems the JVM might find itself on? Free followup question: what is the subset of systems we need this functionality for?

Answer these and you can start on your solution.

Because asking for this in core Java is pretty much asking for the impossible.

Comment: you mean there's noting to do that task in java...no solution!!!

Comment: Like I said. If you can describe how to determine what upgrade means in a platform nonspecific manner, then it is easy to do this stuff in core Java.

Comment: The solution is to write your own solution, really.

Comment: I can't get you, what heuristics determining are you talking about?

Comment: How would you, yourself, determine the last time a system had been updated in some manner? Now, do that for each OS and release version you want to support. These are your heuristics. There is no one platform or release non specific way to get this information. You have to determine your list of OS types you want to handle (Linux, Windows, etc.) release (some distribution, some version of Windows, 32-bit, etc.) and then figure out your ways of making a guess about some state of that system. In some cases this will only be a guess. These are heuristics.

Comment: Ok but if i want it only for windows then how can i do it, still not found any way to do that...

Comment: "How would you, yourself, determine the last time a system had been updated in some manner?" Now, try to abstract this into commands you can run or files you can read. There is a command "wuauclt.exe" that you might be able to get info out of, but it depends on system settings if it works. See: https://superuser.com/questions/462425/can-i-invoke-windows-update-from-the-command-line

Comment: there must be something like `systeminfo | find ": KB"` by which one could be able to find last update date of OS. Thanks anyway...

Comment: There really isn't, to my knowledge. Even Microsoft has changed what an upgrade means, and the tools used to get that administrative information over the years. There _may_ be an unattended administration API used by one of their enterprise tools, but those will be closely guarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperties("os.version");
```

Doubt you can get the date, so "when" might be a problem, but the version should give a rough idea.

Comment: by `os.version` i'll only get os version not the os last updated info